# Same Enteries in mysqld.log

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I see my mysql log file and found approx 90% of below mention entries

2018-03-06 10:42:37 14950 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'ad@16.8.2.3:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 399,
 Error_code: 2003

Unfortunately, i dont have access on above machine and i have dropped the user ad@16.8.2.3 but still its showing log entries. I want mysqld.log file must ignore this entry. Any idea

Comment: it seem you are using this use in change master or make sure that both master & slave have different server ids. Also make sure auto.conf shouldn't be same on master & slave. the user specified in change master should be there on master so slave thread can connect it.

Comment: I already mention "I have dropped this user". But still getting this user log after every 2 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your MySQL server is configured as a slave server in a master - slave replication setup. If all you want is for the error messages to go away, then you can simply do:

`STOP SLAVE;`

And to remove the slave configuration:

`RESET SLAVE;` (Use `RESET SLAVE ALL;` on MySQL 5.5.16 and later versions.)

Also edit /etc/my.cnf (and any included .cnf files inside it) to remove any lines starting with `master-` and `replicate-`.

While the above is sufficient to prevent the server from attempting further replication, you can also restart mysqld to remove slave status information available from commands such as `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`.